# How to separate a dictionary in a column into two separate columns with list of keys in one and list of values in another in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want the keys in the form of a list as separate under one column and values in the form of list under another column.

What I have:

```
---------------
|dict_col_name|
---------------
|{A:1,B:2,C:3}|
|{D:4,E:5}    |
.
.
```

What I want:

```
------------------------------------------------
|dict_col_name |  key_col_name |  value_col_name|
------------------------------------------------
|{A:1,B:2,C:3} |  [A,B,C]      |  [1,2,3]       |
|{D:4,E:5}     |  [D,E]        |  [4,5]         |
.
.
.
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: What do you have? A list of dictionaries? Could you please post some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary have two usefull functions for what you want to do :

```
dict_column_name = {"A" : 1, "B" : 2, "C" : 3}
key_column_name = list(my_dict.keys())
value_column_name = list(my_dict.values())
```